# Adding multiple markers in ionic google map

Tags: google-maps, ionic4

I am trying to integrate google map in ionic project and got succeeded in displaying the google map on ionic page. But i want to display multiple markers on the this google map. tried different code but not getting this multiple markers thing. 
below is my code:

html:

```
<ion-content>

<div #mapElement class="map" >

</div>
```

.ts file:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

 declare var google;

@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
 })
   export class HomePage implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{

@ViewChild('mapElement', { static: true }) mapNativeElement: ElementRef;

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

}

 }
```

i want to add diffent location markers on the map using latitude and longitude values similar to below reference image

[image]

please help me how can i do this. thank you

Answer (score 1):

On one project i needed to do the same so i made this function.
So you only need to put a for/foreach with the list you want to print and thats all.

Hope this help you.

```
private createMarker(position, label, element, icon) {

if (this.map != undefined) {
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: this.map,
    icon: {
      url: icon, // url
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 40), // scaled size
    }

  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "content"
    });
    infowindow.open(this.map, marker);

  });
} else {
  console.log("map is undefined");
}
```

}

with loop you should be able to create the markers correctly with the function above:

```
this.markers.forEach(element => {

  this.infomarkers.forEach(info => {

    if (element.id == info.id) {

      this.createMarker(element.position, element.label, info, element.icon);

    }

  });

});
```

Comment: hi @jhervera, thanks for your answer, where should i need to put different latitude and longitude values in the code for displaying multiple markers. iam newbie to ionic and angular, can you please edit in my code. thank you

Comment: Hi @Saif, in that case i have a provider with some objects like that : { position: { lat: lat , lng: lng }; if you use it with my code this should work properly. I'm going to edit the code and put an example.

Comment: Hi @ jhervera,  i tried inserting your code in my project but not getting the output. can you please edit in my complete code as iam newbie to this ionic and angualr. thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can define some markers like this:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
  icon: {
    url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"
  }
});
```

for more information see the tutorial here: https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-change-javascript-google-map-marker-color-8a72131d1207

Comment: hi @yaennuuH, thank you for your answer, in your reference given it was using javascript, in my case using Angular for my ionic project.  I updated code in the question after searching online to add multiple markers but its not working and not showing any errors also. please have a look and assist me. thank you